# How can I get Belkin N600 DB adapter to work on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wifi, driver

It shows up in `lsusb` but it doesn't light up or work? Are there any drivers I can download?

I have tried some solutions but this doesn't work or any other variants of it:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was already solved [here](http://www.brianzier.com/getting-the-belkin-n600-db-to-work-on-ubuntu) - it will work for raspbian too

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) This doesnt work though

Comment: please add your `uname -a` output. What is your OS exactly?

Comment: Its the newest raspbian i believe i just got my raspberry pi two days ago so Im not sure

Comment: rpi b, b+, v2 or v3 ? did you have a SD card shipped with it?

Comment: Its the b+ i believe and yeah the card was shipped with it

Comment: use a freshest Raspbian Jessie image from an official site, then it will be more clear.

Comment: Will the instructions in the link you posted work then?

Comment: @sydluce The linked solution will not work on the Pi which is NOT a x86 architecture.

Comment: Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Try the latest stable kernel from kernel.org

Comment: I don't think the ndiswrapper will work on arm devices as it wraps the windows x86_64 binary into a package that can be used by linux x86_43.